# Putting JavaScript in EE channel fields

Tags: ee2, javascript

I've done some Google searches, and don't know if this is possible...but I really hope that it is.

I'm building a channel for landing pages (marketing campaigns.) Each campaign will be a channel entry, and will customize the template(s) I'm building. Each campaign page and thank-you page will have to be able to include JavaScript tracking code that is custom to the campaign - in addition to the GA tracking code that's going to be pulled into the template. This tracking code is often JavaScript.

I was going to create a textarea field for pasting in the tracking code, set to no formatting. But will EE allow this, or will it hopelessly mung up the JavaScript code? (I have Wygwam fields on this EE installation, but I've read [in another thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/how-can-i-disallow-javascript-and-css-entered-into-wygwam-fields) that Wygwam/CKEditor can routinely strip out JavaScript tags - and in this case I don't want the JavaScript to be messed with, stripped out, edited, or even breathed on wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field set as a TextArea with formatting set to 'none' should do the trick and leave the js unaffected. WYGWAM or any other WYSIWYG editor will likely be a real pain.

Comment: Thanks, Jez! I'll give that a shot. I was fairly sure that WYGWAM would mess it up badly, but wasn't sure if the plain ol' textarea would leave it alone.